# 400 Bad Request in flask/python

Tags: python, html, flask

I keep getting a 400 bad request. I'm getting it when I include the flask routes and when I take them away and just leave the html and anything except session['guess'] it works, so it has to be the routes.I'm trying to create a simple guessing game that stores a randnum in session and then allows the user to guess at the num and it will tell them whether the guess was too high etc. The {{session[randnum]}} at bottom is just to help check code.

Error code:

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2017 14:52:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2017 14:52:54] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2017 14:53:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2017 14:58:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Python.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
import random
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'ThisIsSecret'

@app.route('/play', methods=['POST'])
def sumSessionCounter():
    if session['guess'] == session['randnum']:
        print 'You Win'
    elif session['guess'] > session['randnum']:
        print 'Too High'
    elif session['guess'] < session['randnum']:
        print 'Too Low'
    else:
        print 'does not recognize that input, try a number'
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['randnum'] = random.randint(1,101)
    session['guess'] = request.form['guess']
    return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Great Number Game!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #body{
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id='body'>
    <h1>The Great Number Game!</h1>
    <p>I am thinking of a number between 1-100</p>
    <p>Take a guess:</p>
    <form class="abc" action="/play" method="POST">
      <p><input type="text" name="guess" value=" "></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit"></p>
    </form>
    {{session['randnum']}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the full error you're receiving.

Comment: edited and added on

Comment: "I keep getting a 400 bad request. "  When? You need to describe specifically and in detail (include errors, logs, whatever) what you did, what happens, what you expected to happen and how they differ.

Comment: Edit your question to add the details, don't stick them in unreadable comments. Also, if you haven't yet, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does 'take away the routes' mean?

Comment: it's when I comment out # the lines of code with session['guess'] int hem

Comment: Then say that :) Write like you're explaining to a five year old.

Comment: I had the     session['guess'] = request.form['guess'] in the wrong area. it was supposed to be under app route /play

Comment: Ok, I see what's going wrong. `session['guess'] = request.form['guess']` makes no sense in / because you're not processing a form, this is for when you're handling a form and in / you're just displaying the template. So that doesn't belong there. For whatever reason, flask does not give a good exception for this. So fix that and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah. This is kind of, shitty flask behaviour in this case, it should have given you a trace in debug mode. But it doesn't.